# Retrieve user's custom lists of Facebook friends with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's a hard topic to google, brute-forcing it will be the next step if I can't get an answer here ;-)

I want the lists that users can create; something like this in PHP with some other API :

`$facebook->api_client->friends_getLists();`

I've tried to "metadata=1" /me/friends, but I can't seem to be retrieving any leads...

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into FQL? Looks like you can get this info from [`friendlist`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friendlist) table (but it only works for currently logged in user).

Comment: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20flid,name%20from%20friendlist%20where%20owner=USERID&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN